# Compressibility Factor Of Gases

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases

In the general equation of the compressibility factor $Z$, we define $Z$ as
$$Z=\frac{pV}{nRT}$$
Here, what is $p$? Is it $p_\text{real}$ or $p_\text{ideal}$?
Also, what is $V$? $V_\text{real}$ or $V_\text{container}$?

Comment: What difference do you see $V_{real}$ versus $V_{container}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both quantities are of the real gas.

Note that for the ideal gas behaviour, the [compressibility factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility_factor?wprov=sfla1) $$Z=\frac{V_\text{real}}{V_\text{ideal}}=\frac{pV_\text{real}}{nRT}=1$$
 for any combination of $p, V, T$.

But real gases, in contrary to the ideal gas, have nonzero volume of molecules and there are intermolecular interactions.

The volume of molecules increases $Z$, as it makes the pressure higher, because the collision frequency is higher.

The cohesive forces between molecules decreases  $Z$. As molecule attraction, like hydrogen bonds or dipole interactions, decreases the effective number of molecules and therefore pressure.

This is reflected in the [van der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation?wprov=sfla1) - probably the simplest state equation of real gases, for not too high pressure: 
$$\begin{align}
\left(p + \frac{an^2}{V^2}\right)\left(V - nb\right)&=nRT \\
\left(p + \frac{a}{V_\mathrm m^2}\right)\left(V_\mathrm m - b\right)&=RT
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
Z &= \frac{p\cdot V_\text{real}}{nRT} \\
Z&=  \frac{p\cdot V_\text{real}}{\left(p + \frac{an^2}{V_\text{real}^2}\right)(V_\text{real} - nb)} \\
Z&=  \frac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{an^2}{p \cdot V_\text{real}^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{nb}{V_\text{real}}\right)} \\
Z&=  \frac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{a}{pV_{\mathrm m,\text{real}}^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{b}{V_{\mathrm m,\text{real}}}\right)}
\end{align}$$

For $|x|\ll1, 1/(1+x)=1-x$

For not too far from ideal behaviour, we can apply the above approximation.

$$\begin{align}
Z&=\left(1 - \frac{an^2}{pV_{\mathrm{real}}^2}\right)\left(1 + \frac{bn}{V_{\mathrm{real}}}\right) \\
Z&=\left(1 - \frac{a}{pV_{\mathrm m,\text{real}}^2}\right)\left(1 + \frac{b}{V_{\mathrm m,\text{real}}}\right) \\
\end{align}$$

We can therefore also afford to neglect minor terms.

$$\begin{align}
Z&=1 - \frac{an^2}{pV_{\mathrm{real}}^2}+ \frac{bn}{V_{\mathrm{real}}}\\
Z&=1 - \frac{a}{pV_{\mathrm m,\text{real}}^2}+ \frac{b}{V_{\mathrm m,\text{real}}}\\
\end{align}$$

To address clarified scenario, as a the same amounts of the ideal and real gas
are under the same temperature and pressure:

$$V_\text{ideal gas}=\frac{nRT}{p}$$
$$V_\text{real gas}=Z \frac{nRT}{p}$$

There is need to perform iteration for probably the easiest way to get the result. 
With the $V_{\rm{ideal gas}}\ $ as the first approximation. The other option is to solve the root of the cubic equation what we probably do not want to.

$$\begin{align}
V_\text{real}&=Z(p, V_\text{real})\frac{nRT}{p}\\
V_\text{real}&=\frac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{an^2}{p \cdot V_\text{real}^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{nb}{V_\text{real}}\right)} \frac{nRT}{p} \\
V_\text{real}&=\left( 1 - \frac{an^2}{pV_{\rm{real}}^2}+ \frac{bn}{V_{\rm{real}}}\right) \frac{nRT}{p} \\
\end{align}$$

The van der Waals equation can also be expressed in terms of reduced
properties

$$\left( P_r + \frac{3}{V_\rm{r}^2}\right) \left( V_{\rm r}-\frac{1}{3}\right) = \frac{8}{3}T_\mathrm r$$

This yields a critical compressibility factor $3/8$.

The values of pressure, temperature and volume are divided by the
respective critical values of the given gas.

Comment: We have p, V, n, T. Now we compare 1 mol of real gas and 1 mol of perfect gas. We set p and T same for both gases, then we inspect their V. eg we set for both gases p=1atm T=298K. p for perfect gas is that p(ideal), p for real gas is p(real), both set to have same value and that 'same value' plugged into that equation. I don't see how p is real or ideal in the equation. It's just a common value that we set experimentally. So, that p is both p(ideal) and p(real), both have the same value. Correct me if I am wrong. I am still a learner.

Comment: This all should be in your question elaboration. Your scenario was not clear, neither what quantities are given and what are dependent.

Comment: @Poutnik Well, shouldn't that be obvious when we talk about compression factor, which is defined as ratio of molar volume of real gas to that of perfect gas *under the same conditions of pressure and temperature*? The V is definitely V(real), but I doubt the statement 'Both quantities are taken as real ones.' is correct.

Comment: It should be obvious from the question wording, which was rather underelaborated. :-)

Comment: Isn't P ideal = P real + an²/V² ?

Comment: No, it is not, as the is also $V - n\cdot b$ factor.

Answer (score 1):

Compressibility factor for a gas is defined as the ratio of the volume of real gas to the volume of ideal gas .
Thus 
$$ Z = \frac{V_\text{real}}{V_\text{ideal}} $$
Using the ideal gas equation
$$ PV_\text{ideal} = nRT $$
$$ V_\text{ideal} = \frac{nRT}{P} $$
So 
$$ Z = \frac{V_\text{real}}{\frac{nRT}{P} } $$
$$ Z = \frac{PV_\text{real}}{nRT} $$ 
Hence except $V_\text{real}$ all other quantities are ideal.

Comment: The answer apart from this answer says that even P is real, I don't know which to trust. can you provide a source to your answer?

Comment: P is pressure on container wall. And V is container volume.