# How to derive the compressibility factor for a van der Waals gas?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases

So as far as I know, 
$$Z=\frac{p_\mathrm{r}V_\mathrm{r}}{nRT},$$ 
where $\mathrm{r}$ denotes the subscript for real.

Solving it for a van der Waals gas gave me the following result,
$$Z=1+\frac{p_\mathrm{r} b}{RT}-\frac{an}{VRT}+\frac{an^2b}{V^2RT},$$
where $V$ is the volume of the container.

This doesn't quite tally with the form I see in the textbooks.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What the textbooks say ? BTW, why the new question ? Better would be to elaborate the original one.

Comment: Provide the procedure how you have achieved the result.

Comment: See [Compressibility Factor Of Gases](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/112589/35806)

Comment: I have trouble typing it out in that mathy way. As you can guess, I don't know latex and i do not plan to learn it anytime soon

Comment: I did not know it a month ago either. Basics are very easy. But the point is not in the formatting itself, but in elaborated effort presented in the question.

Comment: Ah, nevermind i found the correct answer  in that answer which you had answered. Thank you :)